# New users which are created by django-windowsauth upon first login are saved as DOMAIN\USERNAME, How can I change the default to USERNAME?

Tags: python, django, windows-authentication, django-authentication, django-auth-ldap

I'm creating a website with django for the first time and I needed the users to be authenticated with Active Directory so I used django-windowsauth package, but now when someone logs in for the first time their username is in DOMAIN\USERNAME format, therefore when I want to change their permissions in /admin/ it says the username can't contain backslash!
I have read the django-windowsauth documentation but couldn't find anything on this.

I tried changing the DOMAIN\USERNAME to USERNAME and I was able to save the changes but upon next login a new user was created as DOMAIN\USERNAME.
to avoid this I used the database to change the username back to DOMAIN\USERNAME , but this is not practical after production.